# Can't select items in tab bar on scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Okay, so I have my tab bar set up in a nib. I'm not using a tab bar view controller, I've just dragged it onto the view.

The problem is that I can't properly select the item in it, at least not the way you would expect to. You have 'force touch' slightly above where the buttons actually are.

I suspect it's a problem with the constraints/auto layout but can't find anything that will fix it.

The tab bar is placed on top of a scroll view so it stays fixed to the bottom of the screen when scrolling. I also have the tab bar set up on many other pages and it works fine on those which is why it is so confusing

There are no warnings for any of the constraints relating to the tab bar

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `UITabBarController` in StoryBoard and connect your view controllers to it (via `viewControllers` outlet). It puts `UITabBar` automatically into views so you don't have to worry about AutoLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I'm too far into this to start using a tab bar controller. Poor planning on my part but the page is already built and tested. Everything works with the exception of the tab bar. Is there any reason you think it might not working, I'm guessing it's something to do with the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the cause of the problem.

Turns out it was a tap gesture that seemed to be interfering with things. To select tab bar items I had to long press. I can only assume that the short tap gesture (that was there for dismissing the keyboard) was confusing it.

Anyway, removed the tap gesture and it works fine.